# Can you use a second level domain-name as a FQDN? (e.g. hostname.com)

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, debian, domain, fqdn

I've been doing it for a while and it seems to work ok, but I thought I'd check what good practice is as far as FQDN. Right now my server is setup with (lets pretend) the hostname `myhostname` and I have a domain registered as `myhostname.com` and I the domain A records for www and @ pointing to my public IP. My hosts file looks like:

`127.0.0.1  localhost localhost.local
 my.static.ip.ex  myhostname.com myhostname`

Is it wrong to set your FQDN to a second-level domain name?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing directly wrong with using the parent domain as a hostname, e.g. `example` & `example.com`. It's rather a convention to have `hostname.example.com`, and it's more intuitive when separating different services to different servers, like `www.example.com` and `mail.example.com`. Also, it certainly makes things a lot more easy when adding or switching servers later.

However, non of the above are *fully qualified domain names* (FQDN). An FQDN also contains the *top-level domain* of the internet, the `.`, e.g. `host.example.com.`. (See [Hostname](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname) article on Wikipedia.)

Answer (score 1):

you should do following:

> man 5 hosts

```
EXAMPLE
       127.0.0.1       localhost
       192.168.1.10    foo.mydomain.org       foo
       192.168.1.13    bar.mydomain.org       bar
       146.82.138.7    master.debian.org      master
       209.237.226.90  www.opensource.org
```

---

you can use `FQDN` and/or just domain if you want, but then why? assuming you're already have DNS entry then it's becomes redundant, and in case if something changes in future you'd re point DNS entry to another IP *AND* you'd need to maintain same record in yet another place `/etc/hosts` to reflect that change...